# Only One Value Shows In Target Column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro for this formula:

```
B2=IF(LEFT(A2,1)="1","Platform","Trans-ship")
```

and this formula continues down to the last row that column A has a value.
Here's my code:

```
Sub Order_Type()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    i = 2
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    For j = i + 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 1) = "=IF(LEFT(i,1)=""1""" Then
            Cells(i, 2) = "Platform"
        Else
            Cells(i, 2) = "Trans-ship"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

The problem is the action of filling value into cells in column B stops at the first cell, which is B2. And when I have i=8, and B8 should be "Platform", it still shows "Trans-ship". I'd really appreciated any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stops in the first cell because you have `Exit For` on `Else` part of `If Statement`.
 You don't get your expected result because you're trying to check if the value of `Cell(i, 1)` is equal to the string *=IF(LEFT(i,1)=""1""*.
Try this instead:

```
Dim lr As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A with value
    .Range("B2:B" & lr).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(A2,1)=""1"",""Platform"",""Trans-ship"")"
    .Range("B2:B" & lr).Value = .Range("B2:B" & lr).Value 'change to value
End With
```

If you really like to use your logic, then try this:

```
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A with value
    For i = 2 To lr
        If Left(.Cells(i, 1), 1) = "1" Then 
            .Cells(i, 2) = "Platform"
        Else
            .Cells(i, 2) = "Trans-ship
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Or another variation using VBA would be:

```
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A with value
    For i = 2 To lr
        .Cells(i, 2) = IIf(Left(.Cells(i, 1), 1) = "1", "Platform", "Trans-ship")
    Next
End With
```

All this example only shows values on the Column B. HTH.